# Call the method according to the specified option Key by Pyhon click

Tags: python, click

I checked the python click [document](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multiple-values-from-environment-values) and there seems to be no multiple option switch operation.I want click select the specified function to execute according to the options.

demo.py

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-f', '--file', 'key', help='make file')
@click.option('-k', '--kill', 'key', help='kill proc')
@click.option('-p', '--proj', 'key', help="get proc")
def main(key):
    click.echo(key)

def make_file():
    print("make file")

def kill_proc():
    print("kill proc")

def get_proc():
    print("get proc")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

expected result:

> python demo.py -k 8080

> kill proc

Comment: you will have to use `if/else` inside `main` to executed expected command. But maybe it would be simpler to create many commands with own name - instead of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you would have to use `if/else` to run expected command.

But you could rather use `@click.group()` to create subcommand

```
import click


@click.group(chain=True)
def main():
    pass


@main.command('m')
#@click.option('-k', '--key', help="proc ID")
@click.argument('key')
def make_file(key):
    print("make file", key)


@main.command('k')
#@click.option('-k', '--key', help="proc ID")
@click.argument('key')
def kill_proc(key):
    print("kill proc", key)


@main.command('p')
#@click.option('-k', '--key', help="proc ID")
@click.argument('key')
def get_proc(key):
    print("get proc", key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then you can run command without `-` (and commands may have own options

```
script.py k 8000

script.py p 8000
```

Because I used `chain=True` in `group` so I can run together

```
script.py k 8000 p 8000
```

---

Doc: [Commands and Groups](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/) and [Advanced Patterns](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/)

---

**EDIT:**

Without `group` probably you would have to use `if/else` and unique names for options

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-f', '--file', 'f_key', help='make file')
@click.option('-k', '--kill', 'k_key', help='kill proc')
@click.option('-p', '--proj', 'p_key', help="get proc")
def main(f_key, k_key, p_key):
    #print(f_key, k_key, p_key)
    
    if f_key:
        make_file(f_key)
    if k_key:
        kill_proc(k_key)
    if p_key:
        get_proc(p_key)

def make_file(key):
    print("make file", key)

def kill_proc(key):
    print("kill proc", key)

def get_proc(key):
    print("get proc", key)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can also run many options at once but commands can't have own options.

```
script.py -p 8000 -k 1234
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can these three commands be mutually exclusive？Is there a way to use option while using group model: ·`-k','--kill'`?

Comment: if you remove `chain=True` then you can execute only one command. If you try to run many command at once then you get error - so it be mutually exclusive but probably you expecet something with error. I think you could use `chain=True` and global variable to control if previous comman was executed - ie. `executed = True/False` - and this way you can skip other commands without errors. When you use group command then every command may use other options - I put `-k` in comment to show that it can be used but at this moment I didn't need it.